# Fill in the Blanks, Please!

Tags: code-golf, string, substitution

<sub>(No, not [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/70432/mutually-fill-in-the-blanks) nor [any of these](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/search?q=fill+in+the+blanks))</sub>

Given a string and a list of strings, fill in the all blanks in the input string with corresponding strings.

### Input/Output

The input string contains only alphabetic characters, spaces, and underscores. It is nonempty and does not start with an underscore. In other words, the input string matches the regex `^[a-z A-Z]([a-z A-Z_]*[a-z A-Z])?$`

Every string in the input list is nonempty and contains only alphanumeric characters and spaces. In other words, they match the regex `^[a-z A-Z]+$`.

A blank is a contiguous sequence of underscores (`_`) which is neither preceded nor proceeded by an underscore.

The input string contains `n` blanks for some positive integer `n`, and the list of strings contains exactly `n` strings.

The output is obtained by replacing each `k`-th blank in the input string by the `k`-th string in the input list of strings.

### Example

Given an input string `"I like _____ because _______ _____ing"` and a list of strings `["ice cream", "it is", "satisfy"]`, we can find the output as follows:

- The first blank comes directly after `"like "`. We fill that in with `"ice cream"` to get `"I like ice cream because ______ _____ing"`.
- The second blank comes directly after `"because "`. We fill that in with `"it is"` to get `"I like ice cream because it is _____ing"`.
- The third blank comes directly after `"is "`. We fill that in with `"satisfy"` to get `"I like ice cream because it is satisfying"`.

We output the final string `"I like ice cream because it is satisfying"`.

### Test Cases

```
input string, input list => output
"Things _____ for those who ____ of how things work out _ Wooden",["work out best","make the best","John"] => "Things work out best for those who make the best of how things work out John Wooden"
"I like _____ because _______ _____ing",["ice cream","it is","satisfy"] => "I like ice cream because it is satisfying"
"If you are ___ willing to risk _____ you will ha_o settle for the ordi_____Jim ______n",["not","the usual","ve t","nary ","Roh"] => "If you are not willing to risk the usual you will have to settle for the ordinary Jim Rohn"
"S____ is walking from ____ to ____ with n_oss of ___ W_____ Churchill",["uccess","failure","failure","o l","enthusiasm","inston"] => "Success is walking from failure to failure with no loss of enthusiasm Winston Churchill"
"If_everyone_is_thinking ____ ____ somebody_isnt_thinking G____e P____n",[" "," "," ","alike","then"," "," ","eorg","atto"] => "If everyone is thinking alike then somebody isnt thinking George Patton"
"Pe_________e __say ____motivation does__ last Well___her doe_ bathing____thats why we rec____nd it daily _ __________lar",["opl","often ","that ","nt"," neit","s","  ","omme","Zig","Zig"] => "People often say that motivation doesnt last Well neither does bathing  thats why we recommend it daily Zig Ziglar"
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Convex](https://github.com/GamrCorps/Convex), 5 bytes

```
'_%.\
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY3NCgIxDIRfZSiIN5/Fm@APobpxW@gmsg277tPXBtQcZj4mJPNQWfjd2p52h2tr7RL0VQKCPo0FHSxFcxfrAuHsXp091Wnibuc8fvXWwpHpNwyiGjc4T2p5iZZVMChXIpRYDScupW8Tzx4T7tFSltEvvLpiTRtWxswPz2RANgwxl/4V/yIqcQ4f)

Convex is a CJam-based language, and this answer is almost the same as my CJam answer, except for `l~` which is unneeded here, since Convex does automatic argument evaluation at the start of the program.

Explanation:

```
'_%.\ e# Full program only
'_    e# Push '_'
  %   e# Split and remove empty chunks
   .\ e# Vectorize by Swap
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 8 bytes

```
r"_+"@Vv
```

[Test it online!](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=ciJfKyJAVnY=&input=IklmIHlvdSBhcmUgX19fIHdpbGxpbmcgdG8gcmlzayBfX19fXyB5b3Ugd2lsbCBoYV9vIHNldHRsZSBmb3IgdGhlIG9yZGlfX19fX0ppbSBfX19fX19uIixbIm5vdCIsInRoZSB1c3VhbCIsInZlIHQiLCJuYXJ5ICIsIlJvaCJdID0+ICJJZiB5b3UgYXJlIG5vdCB3aWxsaW5nIHRvIHJpc2sgdGhlIHVzdWFsIHlvdSB3aWxsIGhhdmUgdG8gc2V0dGxlIGZvciB0aGUgb3JkaW5hcnkgSmltIFJvaG4i)

I feel I missed some hidden catch in the rules because this is extremely simple: "replace each run of underscores in the string with the next item in the array."

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript, 35 bytes

```
a=>b=>a.replace(/_+/g,a=>b.shift())
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##VVPBbtswDL33K4icYixztw9oLzsM66nYBgRYZriMTUdqbDEQ5Rj@@oxUnGwzYNEiKb7HR/kdzyhN9Kf0MXBLl@7pgk/P@6dnLCOdemxo/Vh/eDxszFuK811aF8XlFLkhkVJSy2Mqp@gTrXcPu9VP58NBoLYHOo6QHAvB5Dj7gDtwPKk3p00cj6AFoIYtK3xYbXaru3NPklab1YBH0gN027@wC6uq2ijaN@i9Bq9oe2pwlGWn@7wqjNX0DUETCQc97xN4USuYvHTzrVQHM4@AMReAyfe9noXEEL0cFwjLsAg4rBmEUupp6ZKAY@tz2osfFhK5n8DG2jJGGbHX77P2oyZgnEHtd3YLiR8Zxasw2B8Nvot8rWVE6iux5CDULGJammd75fbFjbFxSs4wx8bGo7U79P0Y6b8vBiNBIblRPErWJEjiu6pdTWeKMweqvdQ2q0zmrioID7TndtZwSH8TvlqQ4PXeunV3e9FGdRUi/OMmjgeLpsQL/CvVt8dmIThn0IGTP@vIOEDLJMqiR0mwpb7XqKNobr0FmO@WnUgOk0rpZpgIIjWZVgs6/1a10KpwB6p7jEaYTyYNd4kCZK6YzAYbFwTyZk1WMC8PgzX0yx@WtaoeqnLA01p/lm6Nu09VoevnqijKd/bh7Xd4Ky5/AA)

Comment: Same thing I had. Alternatively, `a=>b=>String.raw({raw:a.split(/_+/)},...b)`

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 28 + 1 = 29 bytes

```ruby
$_=gsub(/_+/){|i|gets[/.*/]}
```

Uses `-p`

The first line is the format string, the rest of the lines are the array.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PcpLCsIwFIXheVdxBw58oFmBG3AsOBAJDd4moZhTchOC2G7dWCt4Zufjj9k8a13po5Vs1krv1OY1@tFykqs6bNVtqvXsfLBC@jvqECk5CFNxWIzQkUOZdckKYk/IiTRdgDuH5i@GJTWPtue55d87wYU3huQRpO6HDw)

Answer (score 2):

## [Proton](https://github.com/alexander-liao/proton), 42 bytes

```
a=>b=>re.sub("_+",_=>b.pop(0),a)
import re
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PctBCsIwFATQvaf4/FWCpXiB9gCuBRciocUfU0oz4Selx4@1oLObx0xSFMTquzp0/dj1Km1eR8PuzI3bpU1I5mKbwZ6mJUELqdSkUyzGG76FKb4zuW/IQ6kEZKEt4DCCp4Bt12O2QWfCWsjRHXhJZGse/NdRcuGGl2GW/SG/fkWI/LS2fgA)

Stupid imports...

Same thing in python:

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 53 bytes

```python
lambda a,b:re.sub("_+",lambda _:b.pop(0),a)
import re
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PcxBCsIwEAXQvacYZpVgKIK7ghdwLbioEhI6MaU2E5KU4uljLers/uP/ia/iORyrO93q00y2N2CUbRM1ebYC9R7Vl3Vrm8hRHKQycjdMkVOBRDWmIRThBF78EB4Z9OfAcYL1cyZYPG8G7MDzsupWWziNwHMBDVfmngKqDv9oKRdUOJmR1gH98pl9wLuU9Q0)

Comment: ...How did I frigging miss that. ._.

Answer (score 2):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 9 bytes

```
'_+'i1&YX
```

[**Try it online!**](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/Xz1eWz3TUC0y4v//avXM5FSF5KLUxFx1HfXMEoXMYiBdnFiSWZxWqV7Lpe6pkJOZnaoQDwIKSanJiaXFUB6QDyYz89LVAQ)

#### Explanation

```
'_+'   % Push this string: regexp pattern
i      % Input cell array of replacement strings
1      % Push 1
&YX    % Four-input regexp replacement. This implicitly inputs the original
       % string, and consecutively replaces each first occurrence of the 
       % regexp pattern in that string by one of the replacement strings.
       % Implicitly display
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>8</s> 7 bytes

```
ṣ”_¬Ðfż
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hzsWPGubGH1pzeEKaTtT///@VPNPiU8tSiyrz81LjM4vjSzIy87Iz89IV4oEAQhTn56Ym5adUAqXzShAK3EGSqQoBICpP6X@0koKSDhwn5mRmpwLpkozUPCTh1PyidJBsSUm@UiwA) Edit: Saved 1 byte thanks to @Erik the Outgolfer. Explanation:

```
ṣ”_         Split on underscores
   ¬Ðf      Discard empty values
      ż     Zip with second input
            Implicit concatenated output
```

Answer (score 2):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), 7 bytes

```
l~'_%.\
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY3NCgIxDIRfZSiIN5/Fm@APIe7GbaU/sg0ue9lXrw2oOcx8TEhmeHJqLW572h2urV1ceUUHVx4qGR3Us5pn7YIswbwaW1pSkm7nMH31BncU@o2AqPIK41Q0vFlDyRiLVCJEroqTxNi3XmaLCXdWH/JkF1ZdsfgVi2CWwbI8IihGDrF/xb@IIs/uAw)

-1 thanks to a clever trick by [Martin Ender](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/8478/martin-ender).

Explanation:

```
l~'_%.\ e# Full program only
l       e# Input line
 ~      e# Eval
  '_    e# Push '_'
    %   e# Split and remove empty chunks
     .\ e# Vectorize by Swap
```

Comment: ``.\`` instead of `\]z`.

Comment: @MartinEnder That works o_o

Comment: Sure, ``\`` is a binary operator. :)

Comment: @MartinEnder Seems like I have gotten a bit too much in how mapping works in CJam then.

Comment: @MartinEnder OK on second thought how didn't I think of that? Not like I didn't know how mapping behaves e.g. `[1 2 3]:_` -> `[1 1 2 2 3 3]` likewise for `.`...

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 61 bytes

```python
import re
s,l=input()
for i in l:s=re.sub('_+',i,s,1)
print s
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VVNNa9tAEL3rVwy6JKGi0B4DPpW0NJeGNmBoCWItjbyLVztiZ2RHv96dWTlus2CNdr7emzfytIin9PncUY@wgVzX9TmME2WBjBU3cRPSNMvtXTVQhgAhQbznTcaPPO9ub9oPN01ouPl0V005JAE@a4eqkrzcV6Dn5ENEeM4zrnc7@IodGGCFrx1OAg8/vj7kTHlNmRxrl2cf0p6htQOGrTwZtR8VH9AAnk7qLWknygegWaCFLWnnVDd/6qtzhyx1U4/ugFqAb/dH8ql@qervEINGVqgddm7my03v5akY1jB0CF1GN2pxEAislp0EHpbSZ4CFZnC5VMMpxKiFIAQ58OHS3zIsAt61BIwiqs86HwLlPpS0xzBeGJRJEhlfy5h5dlHfjzqJmuTyAmp/kjcGvwpEUD1cPBj2kGltZCzalZV4SC0xm4Tm2a7Evvg5d7qtaIBz1yHbeIMLcc747o3AGGASP3NwXNRILLSKObR4xLxQwjZwa/spTK5iAtOIO@oXDSf5l/DNgghP16Ftrrefsw2tEqT/3Eh5b1ERMuwnbN@OrYDdUhBHknDUNVGCnpCVQnQssMUYNeoxm1s378rHZBXinaiIfoET6v@gK5x60J33qoJ2hStQG102tjSZKDQIJihEnZhNtiVIGMyaoGBeGkeb5nfYX54vfwE)

Damn.

### [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 63 bytes

```python
import re
f=lambda s,l:l and f(re.sub('_+',l[0],s,1),l[1:])or s
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VVNNi9tADL3nVwhfNmlD6fYY6KlsS/fSpV0IdAlmYsuZIeORGclJ/etTaZxNtwJbM/p8erKHSTylT5dL6AfKAhkX3efo@n3rgNdxE8GlFrplxg887pd39fu7dXz5uFvz@n6lp/vNbkUZ@CJ52ixA5exDRHjOI853kyGHJFrlXUjDKMvVaoF/GhwEHn58fciZ8hw6OOZL9exDOjDUJtBpcUXIqHWp2IA68HRWawk7Uz4CjQI1bIlaTNX6pboZ98hSraveHVET8PX@SD5Vu0X1HWJQz9xqj40b@XrTe3lrDysYGoQmo@s1OQgEVs1OAndTqdPBRCO4XLLhHGLURBCCHPh4rW8R5gHvagJGEeVpng@BchtK2GPorwjKJIkMr0WMPLqo55NOoiq5PIHqn@QNwa/SIigfLh6td5dpLmQo6hmVeEg1MRuFZtnOwL74MTe6tWgNx6ZBtvE6F@KY8b8TgSHAJH7k4LiwkVhoJrOr8YR5ooR14Nr2U5DcyASmHvfUTupO8i/gmzkRnm5D21yvj7MNzRSkN2akfDCvCFnvJ6xfxVbAbiode5Jw0jVRgpaQFUJ0LLDFGNXrMZtZN@/Kx2QZ4p0oiX6CM@rP0BRMLejOW2VBq8KtUR1dNrQ0GCnUCSYoQJ2YTrYlSBhMG6FgVup7m@Z3OFzfu78)

Comment: [60 bytes](https://tio.run/##PU6xasNADN3vK8QtcagJpWMgYwrt0iXQoQRzvsj1Eft0SGccf70r223fIPGepPeUptxSfJk93RBOwNbaOfSJOAOjkbI7hZiGXOxN4hAX8SBDXeyqp13Zub6@OaiO3SFRKp73pexnNTAm83Q0oBjb0CFceMCNL8AHeljyDD48pgznj9czM/G2kpzIbC9tiN8C1QJoiEHfFFQ/WjWgBloaVV3XRuI70JChgk9S52jLL/sv1ijZlrZ3d9QD/OPv1EZ7NfYNuqCTLapG7wb5ZcrXqhmLYfAIntH1ehwyBNEuLgdpJnv9AQ "Python 2 – Try It Online") by passing `re.sub` a function

Comment: @Stephen Eh... That's just too close to your solution. I'll just stick to this and find more obscure solutions. :P

Comment: [53 bytes](https://tio.run/##dY3BasMwEETv@YpBl9hUhNJjoNdAcy700BYjO@tKxNYKrYzJ17sbN01PncMuM8zuS5fiOT4th@ePZXBje3IQO@wz7WRqq23zsLW3uNkPu8Speqyt1JswJs4FmZaUQyw4VDCvPsQvQXMVes7Q10KYPa8ZuIfnWdO1NnM@g6eCBm/MJ4rG4t3c05akGGtGdya9oF9/ZB/NJ@rNH/YFQ9DSD7alzk1yc@rXqTyDf3XFho7QZXKjIkJBEN3iSpD@orS76uUb) by using a function to improve @Stephen's proposal.

Comment: @JonathanFrech yeah, but that's exactly [my answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/143357/65836) already :P

Comment: @Stephen Oh; did not see your answer... :d

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 25 + 1 (-p) = 26 bytes

```perl
@a=eval<>;s|_+|shift@a|eg
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Pcq7DgIhFITh3qc4odKopZWXbG1tYkkwHvaQXRkCKA3PLq6b6HTz5Q8cx11rnTnyy4yH0z5Vva5JnM2dqdy3dhHn@0T6O7KIlAWJqQhmI1gSlEnnrCAOhGcmTVfgzn6xVH@7ccpqox5m4Knn3z9DvFq9EbKDT20bPg)

Comment: Came up with basically the same, except using `<>` to negate the `eval` and `shift`: [Try it online!](https://goo.gl/Ysn18b "Perl 5 – Try It Online"). There's got to be a way to avoid the replacing the newlines...

Comment: This subroutine also has 26 bytes: `sub{shift=~s|_+|shift|egr}`. If you reversed the arguments, you could use `pop` and get it [down to 22 bytes](https://tio.run/##PY1BCsIwFETX5hRDcKGoS1elHsC14DJY/GlKbX9IUoIYvXpMizir4fGGseQexzw8sdaos5@al2Vbf3xSu1Raota9cyWs68ZQnMNpI1byzGaUe8jh1hOCITTkwwwiux48hR8o6sV0Y@uh5kCzKzp7QjS8MLCG4Vjoov33ClfmO5UXsa3yFw).

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 10 bytes

```
s.i:E"_+"3
```

**[Try it here!](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=s.i%3AE%22_%2B%223&input=%5B%22work+out+best%22%2C%22make+the+best%22%2C%22John%22%5D%0A%22Things+_____+for+those+who+____+of+how+things+work+out+_+Wooden%22&debug=0)**

## How it works?

```
s.i:E"_+"3   Full program.

   :E    3   Split the second input on matches of the regex...
     "_+"    The regex "_+" (matches 1 or more underscores)
 .i          Interleave the elements of the split list with the input.
s            Join to a string.
```

Answer (score 1):

## [RProgN 2](https://github.com/TehFlaminTaco/RProgN-2), 11 bytes

```
x='_+'³[x‘r
```

Takes a string and a stack of strings on the top of the stack.

The first (top) element of a stack is to the right, hence input is right to left.

### Explained

```
x='_+'³[x‘r
x=          # Set the stack of replacements to x
  '_+'³   r # Replace each chunk of _'s with the function...
       [    # Pop off the group of _'s
        x‘  # Pop the top element off x. Use that.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Kyooyk/P0zX6r@SpkJOZnaoQDwIKSanJiaXFUB6QDyYz89KVuDSUihNLMovTKpUUlDJLFDKLQXRyqkJyUWpirpLm/wpb9Xht9UOboyseNcwo@v8fAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 12 bytes

```
„__¤:sv'_y.;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//UcO8@PhDS6yKy9TjK/Ws///3TItPLUstqszPS43PLI4vycjMy87MS1eIBwIIUZyfm5qUn1IJlM4rQShwB0mmKgSAqDyuaCUFJR04TszJzE4F0iUZqXlIwqn5Rekg2ZKSfKVYAA)

**Explanation**

```
„__¤:          # replace all runs of multiple "_" with a single "_"
     sv        # for each y in the list of replacements
       '_y.;   # replace the first instance of "_" with y
```

Comment: [whoops](https://tio.run/##PY0xDsIwDEV3TmF1YWGAgUuUhQ0JhCyXmiZSmqDGatWNc7BxCCRmehMuEmIJ8PDf17f8vVxTteKU5vi6T49NfF9v07MsU9oy/oYBMdII6tsgtiexwUMdOCKCoyiwY@fy1nCnMUJFYqxv9EIMSYTBjDAwdHzSzNdgBWqyLrfC/xE66maHIlxcsSjCWdhDNlqg9JIFPFtlVK9paFvO2Nvmq8cP) [fixed for +3 :p](https://tio.run/##PY0xDsIwDEV3TmF1YWGAgUuUhQ0JhCyXGhopTVBjUXXjHGzMzJU6tzfhIiGWAA//fX3L38s1FSuOcY7jc@o3YerHYXy9749pyPMYt4y/YUAM1IH62ou5kRjvoPQcEMFSENixtWlbcaMxQkFSGXfRC6lIArRVBy1DwyfNXAlGoCRjUyv8H6GlZnbI/NVmi8yfhR0kowVKJ0nAsVEG9Zr6uuaEvbl89fgB)

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer: Thanks for noticing. I rolled back to my previous version which handled that.

Answer (score 1):

## Java 8, 57 bytes

```java
a->s->{for(String i:a)s=s.replaceFirst("_+",i);return s;}
```

When I read the challenge I at first thought we should make a grammatically correct sentence with the words being in random order, but just replacing lines with each sequential word is easier. ;)

**Explanation:**

[Try it here.](https://tio.run/##nVRRa9tADH7vrxB@SljiH7CseRl0rDAo66CwMczFlutrzidzOieYkt@eSWcn3SCDLQe2zpIsf98nnV/MziypQ/9SbY@lM8zwxVgPrzcAHE20JbxISt5H6/K692W05PO7afPhMQbrn3/8XPxD1gJGu15DCbdwNMs1L9evNYXZGAD73sz5lvOAnTMl3tnAcZYV77KFna8Cxj544NXhuLoRdF2/cYJuArkjW0EryGcnSGDmSgLgceCIbU59zDsJRednZW66zg0zj3s45b9CtqewBcmDDXLMFpC1ZosQGzw77qnxGRzmqbCuqVD2rZEiDIUuEEryFjHCvqHkA6qhob14U9r5QwU8EVXos/l89Z9gbYlQBjRttshsBMtiWbTgeriI8DM4K2xGhBssTc/Tkzynu1S@AocnUSZTkXrujZP9TjQT400YQOxXai4DqmGgHkxIMGBvndMhiATB8nYCqhkagcYUBIwxOpz0RaBQ2ZR2b9uJyjVK9mWJrPLVxro@4B87AqWEPjY9W8NJbc@RLo/BYwJtpcPGbZVNHWiEpryKkWdswBckJ02GQj1PI9WPTR/KRrheQUF1Pl1G@zy2xP/mRgrPGo2R/tKOAncYBvJYWC50UhOD83wAU4sbqgYJ@/iW8EmDCA/Xyk@dKkx1RA8Jtolqvc4QeLRqtTugXmpb5fbdPk/3S1QesDgtnS02QyLQUrQ7o38kqAhZGMn/LsITOifRBoO65WyYdEr1DcUivWwG2CMELBPFCuS4VTIgUhXOHyqcCYm8oDncHI6/AA)

```java
a->s->{            // Method with String-array and String parameter and String return-type
  for(String i:a)  //  Loop over the input-array
    s=s.replaceFirst("_+",i);
                   //   Replace the first line (1 or more adjacent "_") with the substring
                   //  End of loop (implicit / single-line body)
  return s;        //  Return the result
}                  // End of method
```

Answer (score 1):

## [C# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), <s>97</s> 96 + 18 bytes

<sub>Saved 1 byte thanks to **Kevin Cruijssen**!</sub>

The 18 bytes are for using `System.Linq`.

```cs
s=>l=>string.Concat(s.Split('_').Where(x=>x!="").Zip(l.Concat(new[]{""}),(x,y)=>x+y).ToArray());
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hZFfS8MwEMCf3ac4@7IEa7/AbEEEwaEgbjBwjBK76xqW5WYuXVfGPvtM90cFH8zLJXe/S35JCr4tyOGhZm0XMGrZ4yp51vZz0CuMYoZXRwunVrDrXbFXXhewIT2HF6WtYO9C13QGyi1YdsjVeYfH2hZ3p3IMf3PTWQynWZZBCemB08yk2SmVPJAtlBecjNZGe9HP@zKZVOhQbNNse51GkUze9VqYC2mxmc52UbSXsdjGrQzUTSuTMd07p1oh5eAw@HELTUwGk4nTHsNVUZQiGlfhZIa8G1CSA18RIzQVHXNAJVTUhOwRa8gtgWoPOUyI5mgjeZH4Ln0g@yiOVmqJoQ0v6yFVNojK/4SeSmipDi@LnQA02pjuhzyB07w8i3ZEV4FK5QSM3hs82yOQm@sjNtSrE5//8rTU2XRczbUyYb4JniFY5VoI8Y2qs@e@tz98AQ)

Comment: You can change `(s,l)=>` to `s=>l=>` to save a byte. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hZFfS8MwEMCf3ac4@7IEa7/AbEEEwaEgbjBwjBK76xqW5WYuXVfGPvtM90cFH8zLJXe/S35JCr4tyOGhZm0XMGrZ4yp51vZz0CuMYoZXRwunVrDrXbFXXhewIT2HF6WtYO9C13QGyi1YdsjVeYfH2hZ3p3IMf3PTWQynWZZBCemB08yk2SmVPJAtlBecjNZGe9HP@zKZVOhQbNNse51GkUze9VqYC2mxmc52UbSXsdjGrQzUTSuTMd07p1oh5eAw@HELTUwGk4nTHsNVUZQiGlfhZIa8G1CSA18RIzQVHXNAJVTUhOwRa8gtgWoPOUyI5mgjeZH4Ln0g@yiOVmqJoQ0v6yFVNojK/4SeSmipDi@LnQA02pjuhzyB07w8i3ZEV4FK5QSM3hs82yOQm@sjNtSrE5//8rTU2XRczbUyYb4JniFY5VoI8Y2qs@e@tz98AQ)

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 49 bytes

```python
s,l=input();import re;print re.sub("_+","%s",s)%l
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##xVRNa9wwEL3nVwyCQJYuPfSYkNMeQnMKTWGhpRitPV6JlTWLJMc1pb99OyN/7EdbKDSlBlsfM3rvaaTnfZ8M@XeH1b1S6hCX7t76fZtuFne22VNIEPBuH6yXztvYbm5U8UYt1XVUy7i4docc@6Y@Guu3EQp5oKYAjBoROkN5DqgGQx3P5rSOwg6oTVDAmqhCr24nhDm0wZgukBq9Qx7iEPsN5CMZP6Eur9R7cJZXDcI2WOo2jiMe5y8vZ/oxz5YIZUDdzLk2gY0QdbKx7iVXQGvoqQUdMhR01jmOQCIINu5GMsmQCBhdEERMyeG4IQQKlc1pj7YZ5UgRToA9pZ@AZWUbW@1OwV9Q4r/A9zr0IPgfuCQi@znr4t102u0Etw40sAtCMWwlGfAFxSj1lZn1sJuVaUNpmJFVPrdliZxxiVRr69qQ5UzdAY/AjYjok2mj1bGBtfUxkT9BzpUt8AVDTx4LGws53Iw/HxdEanBDVc9hn44JDxJEeDqp5AQkOuc8nY@ZS@RnJBCkY8YDUtgykk6sTjQ9YTE9ct5R91lJQ8m@8LXgLVSEkaU5zddyjc5x1GCQab5zOt9QWZGMTlwy00OHbKcya63khlVcLkaFmahwOvAunpD2fKpUJ9HLxAIBF8wsfmYGj1zxgTtO3ACXzNQ0eMr8yW7lFdLvn@OXwfFX/Ee4w69Yqo6PB2F1KwNYqcNf230JN@rM6fxLOXM3j8XIavGnDhbE2by8OtuW29G4GejfuFaY2azMNduT@@JKbrIHuWULioTXcaAwDhZk5NFpZz32G3@PXpN6ZLMNZXgVi4kI2dn0ZmMNRfAn02ImibKZhPy/eUnkspekONlMWSl7Sc5IDiobR@6L9GVWLMINu2L8Ln4A)

The list input is taken as a tuple. Allowing actual lists as input would add another seven bytes, as a conversion would be required (`tuple(...)`).

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `s`, 6 bytes

```
\_/';Y
```

[Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=s&code=%5C_%2F%27%3BY&inputs=____%20in%20____%20blanks%0A%5B%22fill%22%2C%22the%22%5D&header=&footer=)

Look Ma, no Unicode!

```
\_/    # Split on underscores
   ';  # Filter out empty strings
     Y # Interleave with fill-in values
       # (s flag) concatenate the top of stack
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), 34 bytes

```
[ R/ _+/ "%s"re-replace vsprintf ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZVPBittADL3nK4Shp9LsvYVeelh2D2XZbQm0FKPYcmbIeGRG46Qm7Len0tjJbugYLI8k6z290XTYZE7nny8P3@8/A4pwI5BoR38H6Dj1mLOPOxgS5TwNyccMX1ar0wp0nfSpjpz2wGOGLUmuoOpxT5AdXfaP7GIFr1D9cFpIoLZlpTWJheDouPiAO3B8VG9Ju5atYcPcktV4A/UNQZMIewXwGbyoFcxeuqlgPUDwSmPG2lKDoyw73Ze3gtxUjGxkjfcoIwb9PmgbaiKmCdQ@s5tLdzDxCJhKQTj6EEygzJC87BdIy7AIOKwZRLULtPRMwKn1Je3R9wup2@7GpiGxljr0YUx088Vg5ChmN4pHKQpEyTyL/FLgveqHYW@8usQziDGsZ8bZQaxZxCQ3z2Ym/c2NqXHK@obM@wdN1Vmm@M5NnHYWzZkXiWo6UJo4Uu2lthMtXK7qg3BPW24nDcf8lnBvQYKn/yXhwbrmLlOEQgCz2WgnBJG8WVMMzMt9byx/@d3lraSeqL4sOznBqVDpOfuDTg5HaJlEuQWUDBsKQaOOkrl1hrDMpf1h2Kqvm@BIelOaQrYFHcNWD0mrwhWoDpisjdfzb3i@g/rjHVQfpEr0KdEQUIf4IOVOdfDnfFKW5f597XGA9Xp9/gc)

- `R/ _+/ "%s"re-replace` Replace any amount of contiguous underscores with `%s`.
- `vsprintf` Interpolate a sequence of strings into another string at every `%s`.

Answer (score 1):

## Regex (RE2 or better), 23 bytes

```
s/_+(.*?)`([^`]*)/$2$1/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVPRbts4EHz3V2yEAJESx0l6fbn4lKAocIcUaBE0BQLUcVVaWlmEKVIgKTuOa/56bkkptns4GrbF5e7MznA1V68NyxdsjlAzLsfA60ZpC5Gxmsu5ifYRjXN8bg4CZW0Pduowd9aWXNF@ULYyD8hxApsl06ChQ4YUfr6ai@wsHp3eJi6e/HDT0@Ti@N3x1cXrz7FO9eTqWqCMdXJ@NR0PgBYvQU8up0fpiTmBTcMkz@PoMzfG4z1F5imKku0YCrhOKZGqwDPWwyzteh99ZjavHgJ/HE0uz//8cP70NGXn2@M4OT0b/XVz@2MaDbsG4yJJxp6yuDlxJ79@1TvGO7lkghdQoOA1t6iJNfSnjWfunRs9NILbWA/hP3hBlEmO0vc7xEetSIFs6xlqUOUe2QRBmszShgQFlvkhyZ0s8JngJn9Mh9E8Sm7SyzGU4jDlKzaC5bhPGkbR8Pyqa6YUR2kUwcZTRPFtBGe@@gyia/@o/VMS@RYwmNrb2Br7UdUNF4SahKZMzqSk5ikp3P3oC64eulisyAtbcEmMLz6hZMIgdan0W9nIp/oJCVh@dQr602/4bOOku82m19XV7wv8ypW0vs7qlvAb7xq@yf8gRHfxf9NExmIIfjJj1qMlb1P5O2A/dEcBeKPRtloCIztCIIW5NyYE/4coZkN/a@@myW@Y2874Jk0FbGYa2YLwRNrskrbh/GVDr9fonoCsIGu245e0k7ULx00HvB1sX79V/qoh8ysYYytlEFaVCjE/U5VaUTSkrZRegGotZPCoVIHS7SIzNNbVbIGUi93uk6rk4A4Ep2BHMMOctabf0T78ErLjOUJOkmrHLXDjDLPclOvBXQlr1QLToQZWXAhvtlWguVn0qD7Dn0DFMgUGrRXYa0FQuuAh7ROve17ppLLOH7amZcItqWcnmV6D@6qqwUMA5aSWiYVnK7XqSj1v1vVhK5CZMsYb5COPXSsfq1bnFfXi2jxHY1zJuGg17v4VCIfSVq3hzJBaaawik8oMl6jXSmLGTebdDsw7k8CoGmeqWNOxtPuEf/whwn0nC8KHecO9vC6ASs8ds1YN7jF7W95Ow9YBu1aWL8lvJaFQaIhMMGPhEYWg04reTQrT3bEwBL7CVsySPdUaVkgDnAf2AujqCpJJqLAjygTTTjXCqdKiBOdLwUnrQCK3zjgAp@oa3Xc@999/AQ) - RE2
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVPbbttGEH3XV0wCIyQVi7LToECi0EFRFIUDFAiSAgbqKNyVOBS3Wu4wO0upkuP@ujtLOkofQkGXncs5Z86O/tY7zWtvujBzVOHDsbhY@CI9Flfz6QPPy@dpPn2bqfT2s1pOs/nZi7PL@cN0fszyQB@DN26TZjlbs8b05/PZy2wBpobU314snxQJJxmExtMekj8MsxTDU36aTCoowN9eLsfi6ir5N4GvX6HKWx3WTTq/vZi9@mX2aaln92dpNn2ev7l6@3k5z05o126nramgQmtaE9AnEx8xc@6sCWn1TUZu0W1CA08KeHlqvvEkQlzfrtAD1d9BOFkAD9JeiLQI@AE3v/3TpVHruYR/WmYTj1964zFNPOrKGodJlq/ld8BrJxi1FifujOv68LrztEbmnENl3H2Wk0uToePcFld3R3j2DP5XQn3I9150pMknl8gEx@JyAtAVdgE1@XSxyO5a0dTlHjsbafw58DBp2hZFl61ExXYhDe39j3G77D57@LORa2Ao4xNxxRVihH1DQywa0ohLYSzbk9@CIEAJNyT74dQpskIOqtVblFocT@@ocZNrsEaCI8EK17rnx5Och09BVrIwEG1rlQlgWLEOhuvD5LqGA/Wg/dADe2NtXJtA4A1vH1FjRcxAo0sCxhAsPs6CQL4yQ9k70z7yOuUoqJjsuddW7USzctofQH2gZvJxADUyrbbbyFZ7GlsjbznqkC1yJTFHg2LkZpTya9P7dSNaVL@OjqtaG9t7PH0TWIUuND0bzTKt40BiUl3iDv2BHJaGy@j2wHwyCZhaXFF1kLQL3wt@j0mE9@NYMLx0NDyONwaQ/EbpEGjyHstvT7ST9WHAbimYnfhNDipCFjKrOcANWivZRv4VEpa708MSxI7Q6CD2NAfYI3hcD@wVyNVVMqagwomotNor6qyiOqADFVtBuaDAoQmKFYCitkX1l9nE938) - ECMAScript
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RVJNjxMxDL33V1iratUuEqVInMrCgQPaPa0AqRIsxOnU00TNxFXsaTWL@O0lyZSS0czIzx/Pfs6BUnh3nr7cv1mdnA80e/9h/rtx3B1WS6jIWRbm1ez13cc5zn78wp9388X07XS5OK@mL7e3h@Sj3jzHm2zdL1dQ7an5c/7mfNwJmHKg5QTqWCiX5IoBt@D4lNEaduK0B@4VDKyZtxTximxIFDu7pxxLo/XILk4eIPgMjgQbamwvFyvb9Zsro28ImkS2Q6/gBcWql3aYPLQwcA821Rw4@RByOChD8rK/VC0RxQPOGgYh1UCXWQg4bX0Ne/TdhTdiZMXi7KW3AY@5Z4w2DYBf2E2@1qI@T2vDvrC1icfUwmvGPtRBNCxSBCrIemzlk@tTk9cRsG8aEsHW@tAnuv4ZAlJU14u3kqeNopxFag0dKQ0cyXgxRe3KfBUJhDva8HbI7qj/Az4XJ8HTOBbUxxbBy3gjQJx2aFV58kTm3ylyih1q7Y7VH7PeHGHLJJksWFFYUwjZ6ygVOO/O1ktQMtRZzfK4AU4EiZrKvoW8um0eM1eFK5EJNiEfAnKrFAFLKmBUhEheURAAuesIv/tdef8C) - Perl
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fVRtb9s2EP7uX3ERhEpK5bd0XwZVDYo2KxxsbeC0y7DEJWmJsjhTpEBScZw2@@vZUcpSpFhnQ293x7vneXjHtm7vXx63dQuhgRxawzfE8FaygsfRdHJ4TEjNpCOFblohubmKr5Lsajm1UQoRXhUayYb7AOW4cjYm5JfFryeEJCnMk2wkKohDczlbHeSRjRJwtdE7UHwHJzcFb53QKo5@E9YKtYHABhGuCUuEgovmqwz69eWr6O8Ivn4d8DXMFTWiu5yNf349vlqx8V0YJ4fPJy9fHX9eTaM0LJP/LhQs1DWTooSSS9EIx03gy3nm/KaVuuRYK8XSyVC40J1yCD85yH/6QcYLoxG46po1N6Crb5ltn9oOTI6QSVgN7y/8uy@JNCcDTf8s0bpBa8Wk5dmo0oYzpGmdIbaVAmFUCTALYZF86UUp4NkzQHerbRxsRGNvXr/99MdpF6QYkud5n@gHgn9Shhd6o8QtL6GSDKWPJmExibz@g@ZFnkebKAk3uTMdz4BjNo97gsCL7G5U7QzSjM8/vj1ZLtPg7M3y5AiukfRTB/aFdQxVjHwE@f1keb748D5Kvo8LrpQXTChBLHdx0BaGT9as2DqDN9KLGqQQjOeBR/gkDLl0xiKx/w/7a3DNfB2UNw5v81kWyrzC/rUex@J9kiVfkH4cyktUVnKFb8l4vsrzHh8G226NHjSns3Q878XCRAkvau1DcBNv83k2AvAVMkwXtvmTqQoNNpjFS6Ywnqd@P/skB/iyxj3fYgrpu6PN7sCnhSCUQXb33SDGSXZvp@R5jDOa0PjyM10dJtPwKJxP7@8/1jhNFoj/eSDYBBp3b4fJehP2aY1N4YawnTZb0J0DAhcaZ0DRR8uaW0cbtuUYy4evU12r0QKkQONQYM0L1tmHL/zu75iZioIDCs8aKhwISy1zwlb70aKCve6AmX4N7ISUfvqdBiPs9iGrj/AeqBnRgLvoJH/gwkGbUvRhp6J5qKuo0o56Z2c7Juk1YqaKmT3Qpa5H531SgWyZ3PpqldHDUl@XDDhcDYpoa71A3nIxQHlTd6aoEQvtioJbSysmZGf441ODpHj41Z0VzCJbbHmNIlWEX3Oz14oTYYlXu6/8KBJY3fC1LvfoVu5bwDvv5HA20IL@z7zgnt5g4NpsKHNOj844@ffn5bRs3@dutBPXzE87lJpbLCaZdXDBpURvjYcVmnHvWN8EfoWrmUN56j3sOOBI9dVLwK0rkSZmhcdCRDJDdSuprvDQB@qXAlWO4jkjHLUUgOqm4fRPsfHXPw) - PCRE2
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fVVtb9s2EP7uX3Hxglmynfd1y6w4BTYMQ4piKNoO2da0Ii1RFmGKFEgqjhN7P33ZkZId2aunJFZ4d89zrzwnZXk0TZLnb7hMRJUyuJooZeyJZlP2cJyX5XUnyamGuPz0GcbwvvvTfD6bXFR/LhZ/fMy/n@fBszmJB8Fx/3VIgk9fyOd@eHJ4fnh28hzumnaH0C/HcRl1XrxxdKYZLa47XFooNX7GTGulg0RJY8E77xfMGDpl4ZOx6WiUoAFcXUEjdf96OZOpiEAzW2kJZ9EKHKVZSEsfGs7wqdG2HXU/eBPwp24YreqMUyZ4MT6NAAsikEpTOWWBV8mhf9H6NdmwVkh6GdtAHtEQrsab8wTPa9p@xmUae/KarG9CeOoAPpnSEESRGQzWEvfwDIIDZ9Q4@e33t2@jjZYJw7xJ34zHvbu7HkJrxGCwg1l9HeRD2ViamnrVWfmGFJTLYB2NRwwG5cG4Z3rL5UFQl8iJwheCrXpHHuTtrk6Xy3UVvWD43eXw1WW4I11enA9//GF4dv4KNTgbSY4dOgzC/uD46vr1l@6wjnfjb6uTN/KeCp7WveOWuXYChlcn1ZQbx7jVg7KJ8cDsTaGPHcHanvbaNNk2jVnTZPtpsi0aNxwX57EFhUz@0o1G/taNRlLFhUrjIgJaWQWmZYEzUlAbZ1wbGyspFrDcUVEhotY4oVvs153sRZC5wTJzbpMcG5mt25pQnIYe740AQ1mOYScY7vRRPTgTvKqzqIUy@1AufrMP9fB/qId9qKJGfTuGv/eV6yuoKaLMFuo/JYzaqJRltBJ2BFurpvuL6@II1gOWCTqFrtPgIOzbP3UUfo21A0aLoByCwpHwMBxyLqe4YcrKtjrnrt@j2z/eaMqs4JIFdVRcDmv7MNpdFY8hoNzNaOC6jk4ex2cv@6LZMW2Ue9qBqMruTGSsWSlowgLvc4gJDMHgL6awxeL8e/S4ia5d2I2R06ADtc623jdbkSSOBcvaqklt0RT3NOqsnj/mGK2B2D0@L5sr7Pg8V14GKoNczVHqzeZKz3xqMdwqlTJJNpIJM5YUdMbQltWnNyqXnRsQHIW1gwlLaGWaE579JzITnjBI3FcY4Ra4IYZabrJF5yaDhaqAao@BORfCVRfvs@Zm1rA6C6eBnMZ40Zm1gjW5MFA65d7sDS8av5JIZYlTVqaigtxjzERSvQDyXuWdD56UY7ZUzJy3TKsa6vzGdRw2BxkrY1yBnOS2DuXnvMJli7GQKknwm5VklItKs81bgSBM2rwynBrMFudaYZGymN0zvVCSxdzErtre86ZIOCYFm6h0gWrc1BuDX52Swbs6LfA/1BXcpVcLmNJTQq1VnXcsXj@unIYuPHehLL/HeisJqWIGnQmKt@2WCYHanGknxt5RPwQOYXNqsTz5AuYMpynx3lPA1qWYJrLCxlEsqCaqFERllkkgDgpEWgKScUsMASCqKBj5i0/d3z@J2wrm@Uj4uxP7q/Mv) - Boost
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVNtb9s2EP6uX3E1BlhKNSdOmq21pxVtZxQu0qZIsgWY44q0dbIIU6TBo@KoXX97dpSyBANqwy/33Ntzz512ra@sOblX9c46D9RS6nAKLnODweCeDvPn8ejgdSLixRexPEgOb45vxof37FuMJz@Pl5EqwS2Ols@yIQ0n4KQihMvWeHk3c866ePhRESmzgQENhklUZG7RZ1lXxEUCygChHzVGWRPzv9hJs8H4xcv09GWSpE/Iq1/T8fHp/6BfTtNXJ4x8O6jlLuaC6eCnODl4Pvrt99dfBsn35IeE5uZWalVAgVrVyqNjWg4ycCPaaeWZVKCn0cQueZa9@GGNa2d5JNPUK3Rgy6daxMVKLTeUHU1hbRvjs3FUWgdlmNQtTpaTCLh8mWXDDQvWhxxFgJpwAl0q/JPBt6EaTtwG70bz95/OL2bv3lzOUhjWDOLo459nV/Oz@aeAUIf8cX715uyMzbvO/Gt28fb8cvZ9US4jYsWPl91GWfkpfOVugZDupG9pRL5QpmcVhtYJSFOAXvB2meSNYZY604ujbt2wr5RGGHM81EE0HFGzYqlSoBR02g@U9oMkU@6SQc33weFcv16EmkcTWDmU267l1wnsnDI@TiKmNp4@WGiKTCf3VxWfDkEeXhBY87HyLvaV7bAgfWX3jHZhe@u2YBsPOVxbW6ARj8gKyYtabpFjsbc@2MpEc9CKwb7BCteyoQeL7e6bKwu1Rlgz5VooD4oESa@obKN5Ca1tQLouB/ZK63Dq3oJTtH2oGiKCByqZ23DsngXsZ8HwFKgu7IOqH/oaYawXwdlQI7W4Zc7CSNeCuLBVdNkVVTyt1NvQrXS2Tw19856Hr8DkligIFJDrnsq7qnFrXqAWzXqNRKKUSjcOH38taIHGVw0pSTytIW9ZpDLHW3StNZgryoPaXedHkYBsjStbtOw2/ingfXAifO7Hgu4tg@BhvB5A6zZCem@jz5j/9wpykmy72rX16pb1tgYKi8TNtCQP16g1eyt@/hjm3cnuCEKGr6RneaoW9sgHuu66F8CrK3hMrgqPjXItnbA7LWzp0YAIqSCMF2BQeUECQNi6RvG32oTPvw) - Python
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVRtT9tIEP6eXzFwJyWBvMH1y5ULFSpRlarlUODE6Uzq3djjeMV6N91ZE1xC/zqdtUN6Qk2UODvzzDMzz8zGlYvq2cEYzs@uzwYOZXrYhvYJqAxcNJrvjdvEJycVIVxVxsuHiXPW9aD9WREps4R92mcEmrSVMo2LjuZ1dHra/t6GzQbS8fdhNOr/eda/ncv@0@@d7sHh4K/Td1/mw18TT8291CqFFLUqlEe3pQ9VugGttPKdtNuUONBolj6HvTG8@TXbjbNcpCmLBTqw2U9W2tJmTDs6gSXxs39KvdUjDahc7HVWPRcdz7tPzBv9MR@gTPI4yaWDR9gkG0gk50paAOscDbBou5@KmTPYjGGGS3xYvX07/XDx92zy/uxqssM8vMZM/r2eXJxPzneI4jXi8z@frqefphcTgN@AZIEgCS7R6TYBTwkyLZfQmfFA2YBfS8UyovGh6RdU0QZFIPVaVgTWdHfJlu3/K9BzrMHylQis1VNrBi/1DAyu62n3slBnHfk4Yjqlkaki6sGMN4E48tuY9W0cerxET5yWh/dtL9hXpaeaPOCOGo@O@kfz8Xj/1uyfcIiORoNB/3jezAtg5RS3lUV6a4ljVi6On2kYH3YGB@@6ohN9EfOD7vD2@PZo@Px8nfOiEsThBZl14HPLw1vntrYFhXK7ZmsNW1t3B7b0EMONtSkasbMskLwo5B0yFpvTR5ub1hS0YmOTYIGJLGl74nP9zcxCJbwwfMUKoTzPQZD0irKqNc2gsiVIV8fAWmkdLpa34BTdbVkDInggl7EFQu9ZzqYXBOtSVcM@qmKb1whjvQjOkkqpxT3XLIx0FYiZzVtXNSkvw1rqu5Atc7YJDXnjpg6@WCa2REGgYLlpSnmfly7hcWpRJgkSiUwqXTrcPS1owZuXl6QkcbeGvGWRshjv0VXWYKwoDmrXmXciAdkCFzat2G38T8CH4ES4bNqC@i2D4KG9xoDWLYX03rYuMX55BTlJVjV3YT3fB6@sgdQicTItycMNas3enP8b2Myzk/UShAifS8/y5BWsERwmdfYUeHQpt8mssEsUa@mEXWlhM8@3SYRQEMYLMKi8IAEgbFGg@E8tw@cH) - Ruby

This is a single regex substitution to be repeatedly applied until it has nothing to match (or until there is no change, where necessary or convenient). (See also the [single-pass version](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/251004/17216).)

Input is taken as the string with blanks followed by the full list of string arguments, each delimited by `` ` ``.

```
s/          # Begin substitution - match the following:
_+          # Match an entire blank
(.*?)`      # $1 = everything subsequent, up until but not including the first
            #      "`" delimiter; consume the delimiter
([^`]*)     # $2 = a string argument, captured up to but not including the next
            #      "`" delimiter; the ".*?" version would be "(.*?)(?=`|$)"
/           # Replace with the following:
$2$1        # "_+" is replaced with $2, and $1 is preserved, but the original
            # $2 is deleted.
/           # No flags - match and replace just once
```

## [sed](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/) `-E`, 31 bytes

```
:a
s/_+([^`]*)`([^`]*)/\2\1/
ta
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RVJNb9swDD3Pv4IICmQfKILuuLSnYRvSU7EOCLA2NRWbjoTI4iDKMTzkv2eUnWQ2LJnkI5/4qK0Re4pkariNNcznEO/v5@X5mZ@@mEIW5af3L2@4@fgBz/vi9fPr3aJI5nRBFr11nmD1/fkBztXAH48vcBtgduNnsFnWXLxT@y/cCGyOR6osL@Xhbpl/LrCjkKZ@IzXirKg50OmXdWEnMLJAwxGSZSHoNWl0cQOWe/WOsJ7jHrhLUMKauaaAV8@WJGFr9qRYmqxHtqFYgXfqnAi2VJlOzpba46qV0VUElXbWokvgBMUkJ81QrBoYuAMTxxzonfcKh8QQnezPVTMiR8CakkEoJdVq6oWAY@1G2KNrz7wBAyfMwU464/GgZ8Zg4gD4k23xPBZ12q3x@8zWRJ5SM285nSNZCCWLZIGyZz0d5avtYqWz8thVFYlgY5zvIl13Bo8Uku3EGdFugyRWkZqSDhQHnUjppMxqj8xXkUC4pS3Xg4ZD@g/4kYMET1NbML4mC57bmxzEcYcmJS6e6HKfyiynmGGs3XJyB9WbA9RMomTeSII1ea9RSzG7dXZmvAQ5I1mTVB47QE96H6uRvQYdXa1talW4EpXeROQ/HrlJFABzKmBICIFcQkEA5LYl/O12@fsH)

sed lacks lazy quantifiers, so `([^,]*),` must be used instead of `(.*?),` costing +2 bytes.

Answer (score 1):

## Regex (.NET), 46 bytes

```
s/_+(?<=((?=.*?(\2?`([^`]*)))_+.*?)*)|`.*/$3/g
```

[Try it on regex101!](https://regex101.com/r/lathHY/6) - .NET

Input is taken as the string with blanks followed by the full list of string arguments, each delimited by `` ` ``.

This is a single regex substitution, to be applied once. (See also the [looped version](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/251003/17216).)

As such, for each individual match it must count how many blanks are to the left of the current one being replaced, because separate matches in a `/g`lobal match or replace operation cannot communicate to each other (there is no persistent state between matches, other than the current position in the string). Variable-length lookbehind is used for this, with group-building to count string arguments in parallel with counting blanks. (I tried using balancing groups for the counting instead, and that took a bit more bytes.)

```
s/                       # Begin substitution - match the following:
    _+                       # Match an entire blank
    (?<=                     # Lookbehind – evaluated right-to-left, so read
                             # from the bottom up, until entering the lookahead,
                             # then read normally again.
        # When the below loop has finished, $3 will contain the string argument
        # of an index corresponding to the index of the blank matched above.
        (
            (?=              # Lookahead
                .*?          # Skip a minimal number of characters in order to
                             # match the following:
                (            # \2 = the following:
                    \2?      # Previous value of \2, if set
                    `        # Match a delimiter
                    ([^`]*)  # $3 = the next string argument (read up to but
                             #      not including the next delimiter, if any)
                )
            )
            _+               # Match an entire blank
            .*?              # Skip a minimal number of characters in order to
                             # match the above (since no backtracking will
                             # occur, they will all be non-underscores).
        )*                   # Iterate the above as many times as possible –
                             # for each blank matched (going right to left),
                             # \2 is appended with another string argument
                             # (going left to right).
    )
|                            # or...
    `.*                      # Match the entire list of string arguments,
                             # including first delimiter, to be deleted. This
                             # can only be matched after the first stage,
                             # above, has finished.
/                        # Replace with the following:
$3                           # The captured string argument
/                        # Flags:
g                            # Global – replace all matches in one sweep from
                             # left to right.
```

## Regex (Python<sup>[`regex`](https://bitbucket.org/mrabarnett/mrab-regex/src/hg/)</sup>), 54 bytes

```
s/_+(?<=((?=.*?(?=(\3?))(\2`([^`]*)))_+.*?)*)|`.*/\4/g
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVNtb9s2EP6uX3E1Blh0NCfOS9c61YyuMwoXaVMk2QLMcUXaoiwiFGnwqDjqy29Pj5KTYEAlWDKfe3vuudOm8aU1Rw@q2ljnARtMnFzL@1Nwqev1eg@4n@3FkzdpHE/S4WBCz/jmaMJYfHPI4/kXvhgwxrI9MrEB@86Hg/2b4/31A4XOR@PfR4tIFeDmB4sXaR/7Y3BCoYTLxnhxP3XOurj/USEqs4Ye9vosylM376Ksy@OcgTKA0g9ro6yJ6V/shFnL@PhVcvKKseQZef1HMjo8@R/08iR5fUTIt0ElNjElTHq/xWywN3zz5@RLj/1gvyQ0M3dCqxxyqVWlvHREy0EKbogbrTyRCvS0NLFjL9LjX@a4dpZaMnW1lA5s8ZwLKVmhxRrTg1NY2dr4dBQV1kEROnXzo8U4AkpfpGl/TYJ1LgcRSI1yDG0ofE/hW1/1x@2ohrP3n84vpu/eXk4T6FeP6Md/zq5mZ7NPAcRH8O/zq7dnZ4TcPyL/Ti/@Or@c/pgXiwhJ@8NFO3qawSl8pbqBmm6H0OAQfa5Mxy@0rxkIk4Oe05yJ7o0hvjrV84N28MHr6xg2Thkfs4iyjU53J0lRpGdLAOslCZkAJqCTrt2ka5PR2rCHq5KWAyELFwQ2tLCk9ra0LRbELe2W0NZta90t2NpDBtfW5tLwJ2Qp0fNK3Eryld3pgy1NNAOtCOwKLOVK1Lg70bl9UmauVhJWToqKKw8KOQqvsGiiWQGNrUG4Nga2SuuwzN6CU3i7yxo8ggVKkdmwzl7LXS8y7Llq3T6oalfXcGM9D8Yaa6H5HXHmRrgG@IUto8s2qaJuhb4N1Qpnu9BQN@t4@BJMZhGDQAG57qi8K2u3KokLr1cricgLoXTt5NPbgubS@LJGJZC6NegtiVRk8k66xhqZKcyC2m3lJ5EAbSWXNm/IbPyzw/tglPC5awvaWwTBQ3sdIK1bc@G9jT7L7PEKcqJo2tyV9eqO9LYGciuRimmBHq6l1mQt6QsjmGYn2iUIEb4UnuQpG9hK2rNVWz0HGl1ObVJWeCqUaeG43WhuCy8N8BAK3HgORirPkQNwW1WS/6fW4fcT) - Python <sub><sup>`import regex`</sup></sub>

A port of the .NET version. The captures `\2` and `\3` are copied back and forth to avoid use of nested backreferences, which Python doesn't support.

## Regex (PCRE2 <sub><sup>v10.35+</sup></sub>), 96 bytes

`` s/_+(?*(.*`(.*)(.*$)))((?<=(?=^(?>.*?_+(?=[^`]*(\5?+`[^`]*)))+(?=\1)[^`]*\5\3$|(?4)).))|`.*/$2/g ``

[Try it on regex101!](https://regex101.com/r/lathHY/8)
[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=fVXdbts2FAa2Oz_FqSFUouOfOG2BbY5iFG02ONi6wGmXYbFD0hIlsaFEg6TiOE32DMNud1Ng2EOtT7NDKUuRYp0MSuQ5h-c738cf__Hnuli___Dl7_tT7EBgIIa1ETk1Yq14IqJwNOxNKS24cjTR5VoqYRbRgkwW85EN-xBiy9BIc-EDKicqZyNKv519f0gp6cOYTDoygygwZ7vLR3FoQwKuMHoDldjA4VUi1k7qKgp_kNbKKoeu7YY4J0ixFJw0Xk6gmZ8ehL-GcHPT1ldylxRY3dnu4Ovng8WSD26DiPR2hvsH0_PlKOwHKflvoO6suuRKppAKJUvphOl6OM9cXK2VTgVi9RGatMCJriuH5ZNH8dPPZDw1Gguv6nIlDOjsY2bbpLYtkz1kEmRt_4nve0ikOWxp-m-K1hytGVdWTDqZNoIjTesMtWslsYyMALcQJORdI0oCjx8DutfaRt1clvbq-cs3Px_V3T6GxHHcJPqM4G8qIxKdV_JapJApjtKHwyAZhl7_VvMkjsM8JEEeO1OLCQjM5useYuHJ5LaTbQzSjE5evzycz_vd4xfzwz24RNIPHbgvrOOoYugj6E-H85PZj69C8mlcd1F5wWQlqRUu6q4TI4Yrnlw4gy_aiNrtQ3cw7voKH4Qhl9pYJPb_YW9b167HQXmj4DrenQQqznD_Wl_H7BWZkHdIPwrUGSqrRIU9Mhgv47ipD4NtvUIPmvu7_cG4EQsTEZEU2ofgIl7HY1QLxw9PU2BwY1lsCls-HYy_Gff9Yk5uPzliEZn8Vbts8NXfzI7oTjTtRcMew0awBYSQKJrux9E0Po-mB_6EYkh8ds6WvWjxbLrDmi6GefNiTJrh4tniSXATTZ8SMiTkhg17o2BvlLc47-8-H7747XWBx9AC9Q-gRrh7NC77Bsk0JtzgBe4m14ZttLkAXTugcKrx8FTs3rIS1rGSXwiMFe3oSBdVZwZKorEFWImE1_ZuhOPmjZmZTATgivGSSQfSMsudtNm2M8tgq2vgppkDG6mUvzacBiPtxV1WH-E9UHCqAZffKXHHRYA2qWzCjmR5h1uxSjvmnbWtuWKXWDOruNkCm-uic9IklciWqwuPlhndTvW4tK3DFVBRba0XyFtO21JeFLVJCqyF1UkirGUZl6o24v6rQTG8NYvaSm6RLZ4VjSJlVFwKs9WVoNJSr3aDfC8SWF2KlU636K7cx4DvvFPAcUsLmh_3gnt6rUFokzPunO4cC_rv4-W0fNvkLrWTl9xfE5BqYRFMcevgVCiF3gJvOTTj2vFmE_gZruAO5Sm2sBGAZ7FBTwGXLkWamBXugajihum1YjrDfwtgfiqwyjG8oKRjlgEwXZaC_SJz39qd-Q8)

This version emulates variable-length lookbehind using recursion with fixed-length lookbehind. But since capture groups cannot be returned from a subroutine call, the regex must make a guess as to what the subroutine call will return; this is done using `(?*`...`)` non-atomic lookahead. If the recursive call detects a mismatch between the guess and the actual result, it returns a non-match, forcing the non-atomic lookahead to try other guesses until one matches.

Answer (score 1):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://codeberg.org/ngn/k), 27 bytes

```
{(*c),/y,'1_c:(~#:')_"_"\x}
```

[Try it online!](https://ngn.codeberg.page/k#eJw9y8EKwjAQBNB7vmJZD02kIF7TP/AseFBZkroxUsxCE4ki+u3Wgs5tHjPBPvWyN+3q0TZr6q1+L2xjCAkP95dSzuI2XtI5A30DQUYoUTJDjTIbSIAoddJ5VmUcQG4FCHYiJ06ovNX4Z8+5YIdXN/B04V/fSExolAp71/njB5wxL0c=)

Splitting based on "runs of underscores" seems longer than splitting by single underscores and removing empty strings.

```
{(*c),/y,'1_c:(~#:')_"_"\x}  x: string, y: substitution list
                     "_"\x    split by single underscores
              (~#:')_         remove empty strings
            c:                call it c
       y,'1_    zipped concatenate with c, head removed to match lengths
 (*c),/         join them and add back the head of c
```

Comment: you can also remove empty strings like this: `("_"\x)^,""`

Comment: and save another 2 bytes: `{,/(("_"\x)^,""),'y,,""}`

Answer (score 1):

## [PowerShell Core](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell), 46 bytes

```powershell
param($a,$b)-join($a-split'_+'|%{$_
$b[$i++]})
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVTbbtpAEH3nK0bIaYICnxApUh6i5qUoiYTUKLIWexxvsHfo7joUJXw7nRkbG2hrCby7c@acua3XtEEfSqyqWUYe90lx87lfG2/qq8RMk@Vk9k7W8XoW1pWNl@n15dfFZ5KOkuVLYq@vX3eT/W40ur0aAT9TuL0aP5fWvQVI5YGCPMSSAsKmJD0DKqCkDZ8qbEN@BdRESGFBlKMbT@FA0duWGOIZVW1WyFtsbf/hfKDSDbQc2wmjKJ3QyIG4jCeTIZ3vUFnGtOksMTNN6Ha813/WFM8OaDOEzKOpe7CNYAMEE20oti2YeXuc@CpEFh3qNIICttSA8aoLG1tVzAKRwNuw6iIThFigNClBwBgr7EqGQD63CnuwdRe71vmI2VH8i1lcm9CY6pj9A8X@DwFn/BZE4FFKqJEzqcj0PLIRf3krXBYMP0n3SfPhim1MtZJwCk9t1CKctiWIJbiUQpDOy8mircJd2fis5ECF@KnJMmTIOVVhbNV4TeOwbAkJqo4SXSybYE2oYWFdiOROqDnKlltkOo6zJXPJayDSNivVWXNT/EC/JYepDalMsEbajxcEqnFJ@ZbNLg6AezEizI@beWCSlHug0bHkHrieCoRqQNwj@TemMlGi07C0M8OfcnStdKcm8VUIO59kNsf08MjgBrPVfGqK9oOnnEuaEwZOsDJ8gxf8CWJriV6O@aYZvcziEUsTuYXlFjYIHjPNOJdrlXO9mRV6obQyXoKZI615PKmIkjUrCwecSXMJemlwyCPQioeDOMC5NNU1Hkv/tG/ya1U5Z1bV5qtuWy/W1XHXoVcZvee6U4twypt5Di8u4wS@4AI@tZxJ4DFCl@EUEvy9xixizkv@mOUBboC/xoryGJoq8sG3pBh8OpxCXuZPdw2PYP1j@c4sr3DbCugzfpYv6Z0JOBbSjm2GvwbRAfx40OpwatmNdvs/)

Answer (score 1):

## [Raku](http://raku.org/), 24 bytes

```
->$_,\s{S:g[_+]=s.shift}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY7NCsIwEIRfZVlELEaPHgS961XBQy0h1sSE/qx0U0pRnz2mpbqHZb9hmNmnbspNqHqYG9iF1X4mxZVfp@0jlctsx2u2zvhPYNWDWbxnMgFDDSzwAKUrNMhh4KZz1fJEkcft6gcKSNHlGvJGqyoSOg@Oh4OVd2x6zBIR0842unlKGwq8pZjXWRo1IAOWuqiOto6aAqj1IOFCdNc1ihT/4k2zR4GViu95q398JFvHtvAF)

Replace and shift, like many answers.

Answer (score 1):

## brev, <del>36</del> 28 bytes

Original attempt:

```
(fn(fold(fn(strse y"_+"x 1))x rest))
```

Wait, this works for 28:

```
(fn(strse x"_+"(pop! rest)))
```

Brev usually does poorly on here but since it was inspired by Snobol, I was happy to beat it.

Answer (score 0):

## [Stacked](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/stacked), 21 bytes

```
[@y'_+'[y shift]repl]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Ky5JTM5OTfn/P9qhUj1eWz26UqE4IzOtJLYotSAn9r@DVRoXl7qxQny8gomCLZBSV9BQ11ZXUDdX11RIU8gvLfkPAA)

Replaces all runs of `_` with `y shift`. Nothing original, as it seems.

Answer (score 0):

## [SOGL V0.12](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGL), 7 [bytes](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGL/blob/master/chartable.md)

```
lΔ╔*№≤ŗ
```

[Try it Here!](https://dzaima.github.io/SOGLOnline/?code=bCV1MDM5NCV1MjU1NColdTIxMTYldTIyNjQldTAxNTdGJTBBJTJDJXUyMTkyJTJDJXUyMTkyRg__,inputs=JTVCJTIyb3BsJTIyJTJDJTIyb2Z0ZW4lMjAlMjIlMkMlMjJ0aGF0JTIwJTIyJTJDJTIybnQlMjIlMkMlMjIlMjBuZWl0JTIyJTJDJTIycyUyMiUyQyUyMiUyMCUyMCUyMiUyQyUyMm9tbWUlMjIlMkMlMjJaaWclMjIlMkMlMjJaaWclMjIlNUQlMEElMjJQZV9fX19fX19fX2UlMjBfX3NheSUyMF9fX19tb3RpdmF0aW9uJTIwZG9lc19fJTIwbGFzdCUyMFdlbGxfX19oZXIlMjBkb2VfJTIwYmF0aGluZ19fX190aGF0cyUyMHdoeSUyMHdlJTIwcmVjX19fX25kJTIwaXQlMjBkYWlseSUyMF8lMjBfX19fX19fX19fbGFyJTIy)

Explanation:

```
l        get the strings length
 Δ       range
  ╔*     multiply an underscore with each of the numbers
    №    reverse vertically (so the longest underscores get replaced first)
     ≤   put the array on top - order parameters for ŗ correctly
      ŗ  replace in the original string each any occurence of the underscores with its corresponding item in the array
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Nim](http://nim-lang.org/), 73 bytes

```
import pegs,sugar
proc f(s,b:auto):auto=s.replace peg"'_'*",(i,x,y)=>b[i]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VVLLjtswDLzvVxC@7KYw@gEFtpceiu5p0RYI0EVgKDZtCZHFQKSS@utTUnk0MWBRIinOcKgU5tMpzHvKAnucuOUyufy0z9TD@MLt9osrQqu6vvLnjPvoerTU5rl7/tS0L6H92y6r16/bj7A5Ye9J7zW/fUgTQ2cfjJRBPDHCUaPVRSN4Oqq3ph0p74CKQAdrogFT0340N@cWWZq2md0O9QJez2/kU7NZPV0hf0AMmnGG3GLvCl9Oeq6rYlnhoPz7jG7WIkEgsFp2EnhcHuqNsFABl2sVOIYYtQAIQQ68u@BYhkXAu46AUSTipV8EykOoaW9hvjCpnSUy/pZRuLio@4N2pia5vIDan@TvmfyqUEF1cnFnHMZM54LGpjuzEw@pI2aT1jzrM8FvvuTeK0MDLn2PbO2OLsSS8WFHYEwwiS8cHFd1Egs9ijx2eMC8UMIucGfzq4xuIgPTjFsaFg0n@Z/w3YII7zcRrM/r72xyZ0nSnRspTxYVoXsO79hdPxsNu6UizyThoGOkBAMhK5XoWGCNMWrUYza3vgxXH53dEO9ERfULHBEy9pXbAPomBlVFq8INqIsuG2vam0g0CiaohJ2YTTY9SBjMmsBgXppn6@pPmC7rZnX6Bw)

Answer (score 0):

## [Jelly (fork)](https://github.com/cairdcoinheringaahing/jellylanguage), 5 bytes

```
œṢ”_ż
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///o5Ic7Fz1qmBt/dM////@VPBVyMrNTFeJBQCEpNTmxtBjKA/LBZGZeutL/aKXM5FSF5KLUxFwlHaXMEoXMYiBdnFiSWZxWqRQLAA) (or rather, don't, as this is a fork, not on TIO)

Full program, as we abuse Jelly's smash-printing.

### How it works

```
œṢ”_ż - Main link. Takes a string S and a list of fillers F
œṢ    - Split S on runs of:
  ”_  -   Underscores
    ż - Zip with the fillers, and smash-print
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 61 bytes

```hs
s#(w:r)|(p,n)<-span(/='_')s=p++w++(snd$span(=='_')n)#r;s#[]=s
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JY5BC4IwGIbv/Qpxglszu5fbJYIO3jqKyMhpo/U59ikS9N@X2vPCc3hO71PhS1sbAhI6nzz7UpcBKw7oFNCjSJuUoXCcz5xThDbZutg6MOLPSKpaYHgrA4ISViSy12NpQBd76bVqS5BSuGm8j76EcBla3SxEy5omj67o9MMoaz/RhAb6ta7kuyruB9vFWWxwUTfB4tv/a1z/AA)

Answer (score 0):

## [SNOBOL4 (CSNOBOL4)](http://www.snobol4.org/csnobol4/), 51 bytes

```
	I =INPUT
R	I SPAN('_') =INPUT	:S(R)
	OUTPUT =I
END
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K87LT8rPMfn/n9NTwdbTLyA0hCsIyAwOcPTTUI9X14QKcloFawRpcnH6h4YAeUBBLlc/l///PRVyMrNTFeJBQCEpNTmxtBjKA/LBZGZeOldmcqpCclFqYi5XZolCZjFXcWJJZnFaJQA)